# What does .split() return if the string has no match?

Tags: javascript

In this JavaScript code if the variable `data` does not have that character `.` then what will split return?

```
x = data.split('.');
```

Will it be an array of the original string?

Comment: Did something go wrong when you tried this..?

Comment: have you tried it out yet? Here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/co91jma1/

Comment: Google for "mdn split". The MDN documentation is easier to understand than the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: Note that you aren't asking about a jQuery method, you are talking about the [standard JavaScript string `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, as per [`ECMA262 15.5.4.14 String.prototype.split (separator, limit)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14), if the separator is not in the string, it returns a one-element array with the original string in it. The outcome can be inferred from:

> Returns an Array object into which substrings of the result of converting this object to a String have been stored. The substrings are determined by searching from left to right for occurrences of separator; these occurrences are not part of any substring in the returned array, but serve to divide up the String value.

If you're not happy inferring that, you can follow the rather voluminous steps at the bottom and you'll see that's what it does.

Testing it, if you type in the code:

```
alert('paxdiablo'.split('.')[0]);
```

you'll see that it outputs `paxdiablo`, the first (and only) array element. Running:

```
alert('pax.diablo'.split('.')[0]);
alert('pax.diablo'.split('.')[1]);
```

on the other hand will give you two alerts, one for `pax` and one for `diablo`.

Comment: Where on the MDN page you linked to does it describe what happens if the separator is not in the string? There are two spots that indicate what should (but in most browsers doesn't) happen if the separator parameter is omitted, but I can't see anything that mentions what happens if the separator isn't found in the string. (But yes, you are of course correct that you get an array containing the whole string.)

Comment: @nnnnnn, good point, switching to the actual standard but even the initial textual description there _could_ be considered only an indication. Luckily it also has the detailed steps that are taken.

Answer (score 2):

.split() will return an array.  However,

The value you are splitting needs to be a **string**.

If the value you are splitting doesn't contain the separator, and **the value ends up being an integer** (or something other than a string) the call to .split() will throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: values.split is not a function.
```

For example, if you are loading in a comma-separated list of ID's, and the record has only has one ID (ex. 42), and you attempt to split that *list* of ID's, you will get the above error since the value you are splitting is considered an int; not a string.

You may want to preface the value you are splitting with .toString():

```
aValueToSplit.toString().split('.');
```